# Burninate [interactive] tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

Currently 488 posts are tagged under [interactive](/questions/tagged/interactive) and none of them has been tagged only as [interactive]. All 488 posts contain [interactive] tag in combination with other major tags suchs as c#, flash, bash, python, git, etc. This tag cannot stand alone on any question and I believe it is a meta-tag for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Agreed, it's a useless tag. The tag wiki excerpt talks about interactive software as opposed to software that operates without human contact. I'd say that to the extent we need to distinguish between these types of software, non-interactive is the one that should be indicated with a tag.

Comment: Perhaps it sometimes refers to an interactive console for that language instead of the normal compiler/interpreter. This interactive mode often has subtly different semantics from normal mode, this distinction can be important. In that case they should be replaced by a clearer tag instead of simply being removed.

Comment: Yey let's do it. [going to the basement, taking out the torch]